# Run/deposit a Powershell Script in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Im trying to run a ps1 script out of the resource Folder in c#

Thanks to [Yevhen Cherkes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7901167/yevhen-cherkes)

[.NET Get embedded Resource File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577716/net-get-embedded-resource-file)

[Load C# Embedded Resource Path into PowerShell Command Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359587/load-c-sharp-embedded-resource-path-into-powershell-command-class)

Got me closer.

Changing

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            string skriptpfad = $@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\1Tool_Final\WinformsTool\bin\Debug\zuordnung.ps1";
            ps.AddCommand(skriptpfad);
            ps.AddParameter("Source", folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            ps.AddParameter("Destination", folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath);
            ps.Invoke();
        }
```

to

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "zuordnung_test.Resources.zuordnung.ps1";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string skriptpfad = reader.ReadToEnd();
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            //string skriptpfad = $@"C:\zuordnung.ps1";
            ps.AddCommand(skriptpfad);
            ps.AddParameter("Source", folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            ps.AddParameter("Destination", folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath);
            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

This only throws an exception with the whole ps script - not known as cmdlet - though, it does read it but `addcommand` ran the script before. Is it simply AddScript now or am i still approaching it wrong ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would suggest if at all possible, you convert your ps1 to C# to save a lot of hassle. If you are intending to deploy this you'll have hassles with setting powershell security beforehand

Comment: You must use ps.AddScript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405384/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-c-sharp-to-a-powershell-script-file/11405544 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.2#addscript

Comment: Thanks, I've got it to work with AddCommand though, pretty sure i mustnt

Comment: I think, using PowerShell files as embedded resources can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577716/net-get-embedded-resource-file

Comment: One more link about embedded resources and PowerShell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359587/load-c-sharp-embedded-resource-path-into-powershell-command-class

Comment: Thanks for those links, i've edited my question

Comment: @YevhenCherkes, just to be clear (the linked docs unfortunately don't make that clear): `.AddCommand()` is the right method for invoking `.ps1` files; using `.AddScript()` with a `.ps1` file's _content_ is a _limited workaround_ (which can be a shortcut if you don't want to manage execution policies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add some background information to [your own (effective) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952809/45375):

<sup>Note: Your problem came down to having to switch from `.AddCommand()` for script-*file* execution (`.ps1`) to `.AddScript()` for source-code *string* execution (from a resource). The following focuses mainly on when to use `.AddCommand()` vs. `.AddScript()` for script-*file* execution.</sup>

- **`.AddCommand()` is the right PowerShell SDK method for invoking *script files* (`.ps1`)** and other *command forms*, namely cmdlets, functions, and external programs.

  - A potential problem is that **the effective PowerShell [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) may *prevent* execution of script files**. On pristine machines running Windows *desktop* editions, script-file execution is by default disabled altogether (`Restricted`), whereas it is `RemoteSigned` on *server* machines.
  - **Assuming the effective execution policy doesn't prevent script-file execution *via GPOs*** (Group Policy Objects), you can solve this problem by **setting the execution policy *for the current PowerShell session (only)*, via the SDK**; `RemoteSigned` (browser-downloaded files must have a valid signature) is usually the safe choice:

    ```sh
    // Create an initial default session state.
    var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
    // Set its script-file execution policy (for the current session only).
    iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned;

    // Create a PowerShell instance with a runspace based on the 
    // initial session state.
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);

    // ...
    // Now, .AddCommand() should work fine.
    ps.AddCommand(skriptpfad);
    // ...
    ```

    - If a GPO-controlled execution policy prevents you from setting the session's execution policy (or you simply want to avoid having to set the session execution policy explicitly), you can use `.AddScript()` as *workaround*, as discussed next - but do note that is has *limitations* and *side effects*.
- The somewhat confusingly named **`.AddScript()` method is for invoking PowerShell source code provided *directly as a string***, the *content* of a script file, so to speak, or, as in your case, a piece of PowerShell code retrieved from a resource embedded in an assembly.

  - Therefore, **as long as a given script file's content (code) doesn't (directly or indirectly<sup>[1]</sup>) invoke *other* script files, you can use `.AddScript()` to *bypass* PowerShell's execution policies** (which apply only to script *files*).
  - That is, as shown in your answer, **you can read a `.ps1` file's content *into a string in memory* up front, and pass that string to `.AddScript()`**; the simplest way to dot that is to use [`System.IO.File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadAllText):

    ```sh
    ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(skriptpath));
    // Call ps.AddParameter() as needed.
    ```
  - **Caveat**: A **side effect** of this technique is that the script-file body invoked this way will be unaware of the script file's original *file name* and *location*.

---

<sup>[1] Note that some modules automatically execute `.ps1` files during their import, and that the module import itself may happen automatically.</sup>

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this explanation, really helped me understanding because you included some clear statements, which those docs were missing out on.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "%projectname%.Resources.%script.ps1%";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string skriptpath = reader.ReadToEnd();
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript(skriptpath);
            //ps.AddParameter...
            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

is the solution for my question.
I included the solutions of the mentioned above threads and changed AddCommand to AddScript ( idk why addcommand worked with reading it from the local file and doesnt in this case )